# Access Outlook email in PHP using imap and OAuth

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, imap, office365api, php-imap

Due to Microsoft removing Basic Auth from IMAP connections, we are converting our PHP code to use microsoft's [oauth api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#register-your-application) and the external library: [php imap](https://www.php-imap.com/).

We have managed to successfully get the `access_token` using the api and provide it to the library like so:

It works fine for two consecutive runs of the script, but for some reason, any time i run the same code after that, it doesn't let us connect, it returns an operation timeout error.

Error:

`stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://outlook.office365.com:993 (Operation timed out) in php-imap/src/Connection/Protocols/Protocol.php:204`

Code:

```
$instance = new ClientManager();
        $this->client = $instance->make([
            'host' => "outlook.office365.com",
            'port' => 993,
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
            'validate_cert' => false,
            'username' => $this->mailboxUsername,
            'password' => $access_token,
            'protocol' => 'imap',
            'authentication' => "oauth",
        ]);
    try {
        //  Connect to the IMAP Server
        $this->client->connect();
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception : ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    }

private function getAccessTokenUsingRefreshToken()
    {
        $CLIENT_ID      = $this->azure_settings['client_id'];
        $CLIENT_SECRET  = $this->azure_settings['secret_value'];
        $TENANT         = $this->azure_settings['tenant_id'];
        $REFRESH_TOKEN  = $this->azure_settings['refresh_token'];

        $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TENANT/oauth2/v2.0/token";

        $param_post_curl = [
            'client_id'     => $CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => $CLIENT_SECRET,
            'refresh_token' => $REFRESH_TOKEN,
            'grant_type'    => 'refresh_token'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($param_post_curl));
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //  ONLY USE CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER AT FALSE IF YOU ARE IN LOCALHOST !!!
        //  NOT IN LOCALHOST ? ERASE IT !
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $access_token = json_decode($result)->access_token;

        return $access_token;
    }
```

Comment: Microsoft had a massive outage of a lot of their services just yesterday, this could still be remnants of that, I suppose.

Comment: @CBroe any idea if the outages have been resolved? Im still having intermittent issues...